# Volume of fuel reserve in MB E200 W211 2004

Tags: fuel-system, mercedes-benz, fuel-tank

I wonder how much fuel is still left in the reserve tank when the yellow fuel reserve indicator lights up in Mercedes-Benz W211 E200 Kompressor (2004).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the class/model, there should be somewhere between 1.5-2.1 USG (~6-8 litres) left in the tank when the light comes on. [Here is some interesting reading](http://mbworld.org/forums/c-class-w203/63375-reserve-fuel-indicator-how-accurate.html) on this very subject. It seems MB has had a lot of problems with their fuel level indicators. Seems the "best defense" against this is to never let it get below a 1/4 tank on the gauge. Either that or keep a can of gas in the trunk.